# shared managed object context in tab bar application update entity not propagate to other tabs

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm working on a tab bar application that fetches places and photos from Flickr, stores the data in CD and allows the user to view photos saved as favorite.

This application shares a managed object context from the app delegate to the other tabs.
There are two custom entities in Core Data: Places and Photos. These have the appropriate one to many and inverse relationships setup.

The first tab fetches data from flickr and stores it into core data:

NavigationController -> TableViewController (of Places) -> TableViewController (of photos for selected place) -> ViewController (present photo &  button to favorite)

The second tab bar is similar but only uses input from core data via Fetched results controllers:

NavigationController -> TableViewController (of Places from CD) -> TableViewController (of favorite photos from selected place) -> ViewController (present photo & button to toggle favorite status)

The problem I'm having is this scenario:
1) Favorite a photo in first tab.
2) View photo in second tab and toggle favorite back to no.
3) Return to first tab where photo entity is still favorite T_T.

I can't seem to make that update in the second tab propagate through to the first one.

I've looked at NSNotification after setting the property, calling save from the managed object context, but I am stumped ... help!

Answer (score 0):

Wow I'm a fool. Apparently there was no core data problem... just my check to set the button title self.photo.isFavorite is a nsnumber returned from CD not a bool...

so if(self.photo.isfavorite) was always returning yes

checking if 1 now solves

/queue emojii

m(_ _)m ゴメンナサイ